# TFTP Server modes not working

Tags: udp, client, tftp

I am creating a tftp application on linux(ubuntu 12.04). I tried atftp server on linux and captured packets on wireshark for understanding the functionality of tftp server. I am confused in mode option. I tried every mode of tftp server like netascii, octet, mail but i am getting plain text on the wire. Please Help me out by providing any link for it. do i have to encode or decode on both the ends before sending the chunks of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read [RFC 1350](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1350/)

```
netascii (8 bit ascii)
octet    (raw 8 bit bytes)
mail     (The mail mode is obsolete and should not be implemented or used.)
```

> A host which
>      receives netascii mode data must translate the data to its own
>      format.  Octet mode is used to transfer a file that is in the 8-bit
>      format of the machine from which the file is being transferred.  It
>      is assumed that each type of machine has a single 8-bit format that
>      is more common, and that that format is chosen.  For example, on a
>      DEC-20, a 36 bit machine, this is four 8-bit bytes to a word with
>      four bits of breakage.  If a host receives a octet file and then
>      returns it, the returned file must be identical to the original.
>      Mail mode uses the name of a mail recipient in place of a file and
>      must begin with a WRQ.  Otherwise it is identical to netascii mode.
>      The mail recipient string should be of the form "username" or
>      "username@hostname".  If the second form is used, it allows the
>      option of mail forwarding by a relay computer.

You do not have to encode your payload; If you are in a PC environment you will not see a difference in a wireshark capture when changing the encoding.

Comment: can you please help me in my another question.

Comment: make it and post here the link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462964/ntp-client-is-not-syncing-with-server-in-broadcast-mode