# NTP client is not syncing with server in broadcast mode

Tags: protocols, ntp, fedora20

I have configured NTP version 4.2.6 server on fedora 20 machine. server side I am using local system time and given  a broadcast subnet and all other options are disabled and on client's side I enabled only broadcast client. I haven't given server's address as according to my understanding server should broadcast NTP packets and client will automatically listen NTP packets and will get sync. but my NTP client is not syncing with server. please help me with all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

you can just run the **ntpdate** command at the client's start-up script

```
#ntpdate ntp_server_address
```

for more details read:
http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Date_and_Time_Configuration-Command_Line_Configuration-Network_Time_Protocol.html

Comment: i have configured my client and Server in broadcast mode. Client should not have server's address. Server will continuously broadcast the ntp packets with time stamp and client will listen it and get sync with it. If i am wrong anywhere correct me. I am able to see the broadcast messages on both side(client/Server) but client is not syncing.